# How to document a parameter that accepts a predefined set of values?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a parameter that could simply be described as:

```js
/**
 * @param {String} source
 */
```

`source` value can be only a set of predefined values, e.g. "youtube", "vimeo".

How to document the accepted range of `source` values?

Comment: This does not seem to be possible. I have opened an issue on Github to discuss this limitation, https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1065.

Comment: I think enums are the correct way to do this, but so far the tools don't seem to enforce anything.  I just asked a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634342

Comment: ENUM does not allow to describe individual values. Thats the biggest downside.